# Optimize Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've got a working query on my laravel project. Is there a way to optimize or shorten this code?

```php
                $transaction = DB::connection('mysql')->table('pwn_transaction')
                        ->join('pwn_transaction_has_details', 'pwn_transaction.ticket_number', '=', 'pwn_transaction_has_details.pwn_transaction_ticket_number')
                        ->join('pwn_transaction_details', 'pwn_transaction_has_details.pwn_transaction_details_id',  '=', 'pwn_transaction_details.id')
                        ->join('pwn_transaction_has_transaction_items', 'pwn_transaction.ticket_number', '=', 'pwn_transaction_has_transaction_items.pwn_transaction_ticket_number')
                        ->join('pwn_branch_has_transaction', 'pwn_transaction.ticket_number', '=', 'pwn_branch_has_transaction.pwn_transaction_ticket_number')

                        ->join('pwn_transaction_has_customers', 'pwn_transaction.ticket_number', '=', 'pwn_transaction_has_customers.pwn_transaction_ticket_number')
                        ->join('pwn_customers', 'pwn_transaction_has_customers.pwn_customers_id', '=', 'pwn_customers.id')
                        ->groupBy('ticket_number')
                        ->get();
```

Comment: Yes ,you can use relation sheeps to optimize your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to read [Laravel eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent)

Eg.
Simple code with `Transaction` model in your controller

```
$transaction = Transaction::get();
```

You can use [Eloquent Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships) in your model

**Transaction Model**

```
public function items()
{
   return $this->hasOne(TransactionItem::class); //based on your model and relationship
}
```

Retrieve with relationship [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```
$transaction = Transaction::with('items)->get();
```

Laravel use `mysql` as default connection or based on your `config/database.php` file

If you want to use multiple databases you can use something like that

Define below line in your `Transaction` Model

```
protected $connection = 'your-connection-name';
```

Based on your comment

Make sure you define proper relationship in `Transaction` model

```
Transaction::with('hasDetails', 'details', 'branch', 'hasCustomers', 'customer')
            ->groupBy('ticket_number')
            ->where('ticket_number', $request->pawnTicket) //assume ticket_number column is inside the transactions table
            ->get();
```

Comment: Hi @bhavinjr, thank you for this. I kinda get the idea. I was able to get a code
```$transaction = Transaction::with('hasDetails')
       ->with('details')
       ->with('branch')
       ->with('hasCustomers')
       ->with('customer')
       ->groupBy('ticket_number')
       ->where('pwn_transaction.ticket_number', '=', $request->input('pawnTicket'))
       ->get();```

So how do you join them?